# System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression could not be translated using EF Core with PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I want to check if a list contains any item from another list using EF Core with Npsql provider. Then I want to get the exact item that was matched in my Dto.

My code is the following (note: Reports.Models is `List<string>` and so is request.Models as well. The request is consumer filter/search):

```
var x = await _dbContext.Reports
            .Where(x => x.Models.Any(i => request.Models.Contains(i)))
            .Select(x => new ReportDto
            {
                // Model = x.Identifiers.First(i => request.Identifiers.Contains(i)) // this also fails.
                Model = request.Models.First(i => request.Models.Any(y => y == i)), // fails on this line
            })
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

I tried both ways using `Any` and `Contains`, neither work. They both return the same error which says:

`System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'i => __request_Models_0 .Contains(i)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.`

But I don't understand why? The error never changes, even in my case when I use `Any`, it still complains about `Contains`.

Comment: The error never changes because the error is cause by the expression `Where(x => x.Models.Any(i => request.Models.Contains(i)))` and not the lines you highlighted

Comment: The uncommented line doesn't seem to refer to anything in the database (`x`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are effectively trying to push your `request.Models` to the database Server for it to evaluate if any of its datasets are in it. That won't work.

You need to request the Models from the database first and compare them locally OR transform your `request.Models` into a set of IDs that the database can compare against.

Comment: EF automatically client-evaluates any expression that doesn't reference any database data, and sends that as a parameter. So arbitrary C# can be placed inside an EF LINQ query, and as long as it doesn't reference a datbase row/column/etc., it should work.

Comment: @ShayRojansky That was abandoned in ef-core 3.

Comment: @GertArnold that's not true. 3.0 disabled implicit client evaluation over database data, but expressions in the tree are client-evaluated as long as they don't reference database data in any way. Try calling any random static .NET function, passing it some constant value or anything else that doesn't come from the database.

Comment: @ShayRojansky Yeah I was wondering what you meant exactly in your first comment, since `i => request.Models.Contains(i))` does reference database data. Hence my (somewhat confused) response. Anyway the answer here is spot on. There's no SQL translation for `request.Models`.